# C Binary Search Tree Insertion Pointer Issue

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement binary search tree insertion but running into problems.

I have implemented the tree using the following Node and Tree structs

```
typedef struct Node {
    double value;

    struct Node *parent;
    struct Node *right_child;
    struct Node *left_child;
} Node;

typedef struct Tree {
    struct Node *root;
} Tree;
```

The following is the insert function

```
void insert(Tree *t, Node n) {

    Node *x = t->root, *y = NULL;

    //follow tree down until we reach a leaf of the tree
    while (x != NULL) {

        //save last non-NULL value. We will insert node n as a child to this leaf.
        y = x;

        if (n.value < x->value) {
            x = x->left_child;
        } else {
            x = x->right_child;
        }

    }

    //The parent of the node to insert is the leaf we reached
    n.parent = y;

    //If n is greater than y then it is its right child and vice-versa.
    if (n.value > y->value) {
        y->right_child = &n;
    } else {
        y->left_child = &n;
    }

}
```

When I run this in my main method

```
int main(void) {

    Node n1;
    Node n2;
    Node n3;


    n1.value = 4;
    n1.parent = NULL;
    n1.left_child = NULL;
    n1.right_child = NULL;

    n2.value = 2;
    n2.parent = NULL;
    n2.left_child = NULL;
    n2.right_child = NULL;

    n3.value = 1;
    n3.parent = NULL;
    n3.left_child = NULL;
    n3.right_child = NULL;

    Tree t;

    t.root = &n1;

    insert(&t,n2);

    insert(&t,n3);

    printf("n1 left child %f \n", n1.left_child->value);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It prints `n1 left child 1.000000` which is incorrect.  It should be 2.  I have tried inserting print statements for debugging and it appears that the `insert` function is assigning children at the end to the wrong pointer (i.e. the `n2` node is not persisting after it is inserted).   So I think this means there is something wrong with `y`.  I don't think `y` is representing what I want it to which is a pointer to the leaf node in the tree (where I will insert the new node n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking the address of a temporary variable, and you dereference it after it's deallocated and that means your program invokes *undefined behavior*. In

```
void insert(Tree *t, Node n)
```

The `Node n` parameter is allocated within the stack frame of the `insert()` function, when the function returns the frame is destroyed leading to `n` being deallocated.

You hold a pointer to it's address in `Tree *t;`, accessing that pointer is invalid after the function has returned.

You must pass a pointer to the address of `n2` and `n3` from `main()`, like this

```
insert(&t, &n2);
insert(&t, &n3);
```

and change `insert()` to directly accept the pointer instead of a local copy of the instance.

With my suggested solution `n2` and `n3` are allocated within the stack frame of `main()` and thus have a lifetime equal to the whole program lifetime, since you would be passing their address the pointers to the nodes in your tree would still point to valid memory after `insert()` has returned and you will be able to print their contents without invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks.  This makes sense.  Inside the insert function I am setting the child pointer to a memory address that is being destroyed after the function finishes.  But I still don't quite understand why the last print statement would be ```n1 left child 1.000000```.  I suppose this would be the undefined behaviour you are referring to?  I would think the ```n3``` temporary variable would have been destroyed by that point.

Comment: Yes it depends on many things, except on the actual code. It's not predictable, at least no easily predictable. Many possible effects are possible when undefined behavior happens, including a crash.